# Is it OK to put all this streams together?

Tags: c#, encryption, byte

i want to be able to open file, read byte, add value (my encryption key) and write it to a new file.
So my question is this approach is OK ?

```
const int ENCRYPE_KEY = 12345;
static void Encrypt(string fileName)
{
    using (FileStream streamToRead = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(streamToRead))
        {
            using (FileStream streamToWrite = File.Create(@"D:\temp\encrypted.jpg"))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(streamToWrite))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < streamToRead.Length; i++)
                    {
                        byte b = reader.ReadByte();
                        writer.Write((byte)(b + ENCRYPE_KEY));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you define `OK`? This approach is typically used for big files (or if memory is limited). Otherwise you could simply use `File.ReadAllBytes()` and `File.WriteAllBytes()` (while dealing with `byte[]` array in between).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *arrow head antipattern* I suggest using a *Linq* query (if the file is small enough - `ReadAllBytes` - to fit in memory):

```
   var target = File
     .ReadAllBytes(fileName)
     .Select(b => (byte)(unchecked(b + ENCRYPE_KEY))) // do not forget to allow overflow
     .ToArray();

   File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\temp\encrypted.jpg", target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this. It seems cleaner to me.

```
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        using (FileStream streamToWrite = File.Create(@"D:\temp\encrypted.jpg"))
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(streamToWrite))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                writer.Write((byte)(data[i] + ENCRYPE_KEY));
            }
        }
```